# Pillow module gives image object error when used with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I wrote this code to generate qr codes with a text file containing data.

```
import pyqrcode
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def create_qr_code_with_label(data, label, file_name):
    # Create the QR code
    qr = pyqrcode.create(data, error='H')  # 'L' stands for low error correction level

    # Make the QR code and add a white border (4 pixels)
    qr_code_img = qr.png(file_name, scale=6, module_color=(0, 0, 0, 255), background=(255, 255, 255, 255), quiet_zone=4)

    # Open the QR code image using Pillow
    img = Image.open(file_name)

    # Get the size of the image
    img_width, img_height = img.size

    # Load a font (You can change the font and size as needed)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 14)

    # Create a drawing context
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    # Add the data (text) below the QR code
    draw.text((5,(img_height-18)), label, font=font, fill="black")

    # Save the final image
    img.save(file_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("code.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        data = line  # Replace with your desired URL or data
        label = line.replace('\t',' ').replace('\n','')  # Replace with your desired label
        # print(line.split()[0])
        file_name = line.split()[0]+'.png'
        create_qr_code_with_label(data, label, file_name)
```

But I am trying to make it better using Tkinter gui,
and so I wrote this code

```
import pyqrcode
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog


def create_qr_code_with_label(data, label, file_name):
    # Create the QR code
    qr = pyqrcode.create(data, error='H')  # 'L' stands for low error correction level

    # Make the QR code and add a white border (4 pixels)
    qr_code_img = qr.png(file_name, scale=6, module_color=(0, 0, 0, 255), background=(255, 255, 255, 255), quiet_zone=4)

    # Open the QR code image using Pillow
    img = Image.open(file_name)

    # Get the size of the image
    img_width, img_height = img.size

    # Load a font (You can change the font and size as needed)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 14)

    # Create a drawing context
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    # Add the data (text) below the QR code
    draw.text((5, (img_height - 18)), label, font=font, fill="black")

    # Save the final image
    img.save(file_name)


def generate():
    print(path)
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        data = line  # Replace with your desired URL or data
        label = line.replace('\t', ' ').replace('\n', '')  # Replace with your desired label
        # print(line.split()[0])
        file_name = line.split()[0] + '.png'
        create_qr_code_with_label(data, label, file_name)


def open_file():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if file_path:
        global path
        path = file_path
        # print("Selected File:", file_path)
        lab = ttk.Label(root, text=path)
        lab.pack(pady=10)
        but1 = ttk.Button(root, text='Generate', command=generate)
        but1.pack(pady=10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('400x400')
    root.title("Qr Generator for Uni-Card")
    open_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Open File", command=open_file)
    open_button.pack(pady=10)

    root.mainloop()
```

even tough I have not touched my create_qr_code_with_label(data, label, file_name) function,
it gives an error,

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Main\PyCharm\Misc\QR-Code Generator for Uni-Card\kjnk.py", line 43, in generate
    create_qr_code_with_label(data, label, file_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Main\PyCharm\Misc\QR-Code Generator for Uni-Card\kjnk.py", line 16, in create_qr_code_with_label
    img = Image.open(file_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
```

Sample data inside text file:

- UC001    SPO2 Probes
- UC002   NIBP Hose Pipes
- UC003    NIBP Cuff

I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: `tkinter` has its `Image` class, so `from tkinter import *` will override the `Image` class from `Pillow` module.  Avoid using wildcard import.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks brother it worked , could you suggest better gui then tkinter